# Why Woocommerce does not deal right with 'unset'?

Tags: woocommerce

I tried to just unset a country from the checkout dropdown menu "billing country".

In fact, the country "GB" is more like hidden and not removod (see picture). Can you hit me up, what is going on here?

My goal is to full hide or remove the country "GB" only from checkout page dropdown menu.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'Remove_GB', 10, 1 );
function Remove_GB( $countries ) {
 unset($countries["GB"]);
 $emptyRemoved = array_filter($countries);
  return $emptyRemoved;
}
```

The country is still there only the text is being hidden:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqtBW.png)

Answer (score 1):

In a WordPress filter, the first param of the function is the value that you will change the content, so you need to return it to Woocommerce knows you changed its value:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'Remove_GB', 10, 1 );

function Remove_GB( $countries ) {
    unset($countries["GB"]);

    return $countries;
}
```

PS.: Always check for the value you are returning or another hooks that are listening to the same filter.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I already tried the way you did it. Same result: option_value is still there :/

result:
"GB" is still there
value "Great Britain" get cleared by the code